# What happened to the variant colors in material3?

Tags: kotlin, material-design, compose-desktop, material3

I am upgrading a Compose Desktop app from material to material3. One of the big changes is that the Theme's ColorScheme no longer has the variant colors: `primaryVariant` and `secondaryVariant`. I haven't been able to find an article with guidance on this change. So I'm asking here: What am I supposed to use instead of the variant colors?

Comment: I've found [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material2-material3), which is written for Android specifically, but still has usable info for Compose Desktop.